# how to get the values inside the li using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How can i get the values of the index `1,2,3` that is inside the using jquery ?

```
<ul class="chosen-choices">
<li class="search-choice">
<span>American Black Bear</span>
<a class="search-choice-close" data-option-array-index="1"></a>
</li>
<li class="search-choice">
<span>Brown Bear</span>
<a class="search-choice-close" data-option-array-index="3"></a></li>
<li class="search-choice">
<span>Giant Panda</span>
<a class="search-choice-close" data-option-array-index="4"></a>
</li>
<li class="search-field">
<input type="text" value="Your Favorite Types of Bear" class="" autocomplete="off" style="width: 25px;" tabindex="16">
</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: You forgot to post the jQuery you tried which didn't work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Map the anchors, return the data

```
var arr = $.map($('.search-choice a'), function(el) { 
    return $(el).data('option-array-index') 
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/m6ces0pr/)